# iOS xcode6.1.1 with proper launch images and icons still stuck in compatibility mode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, scale, compatibility

**ISSUE** - Using storyboard (but NOT using Auto-Layout) my view controllers are not instantiating with the full device size when using larger (6, 6+) devices. On the attribute inspector Size is set to 'Inferred', but view bounds still instantiate as {{0, 0}, {320, 568}} on iPhone 6. The effect this has is that  objects outside of the bound don't respond to touch events (objects placed further than 320 horizontally or 480 vertically), even though they're visible on the screen.

App is targeting iOS 8, supporting iPhone 5, 6 and 6+

I have properly sized AppIcons and LaunchImages in Images,xcassets

I have removed LaunchImage.xib and cleared reference to it from Info.plist

Proper launch image displays on app launch.

Using an iPhone 6 i've added the following code to application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
NSLog(@"Screen bounds: %@, Screen resolution: %@, scale: %f, nativeScale: %f", NSStringFromCGRect(mainScreen.bounds), mainScreen.coordinateSpace, mainScreen.scale, mainScreen.nativeScale);
```

And the code logs the following:

```
Screen bounds: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}, Screen resolution: <UIScreen: 0x124501930; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x170036ba0; size = 750.000000 x 1334.000000>>, scale: 2.000000, nativeScale: 2.000000
```

Navigating through the application and logging viewController.view.bounds consistently yields the following:

```
View bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
```

How can I utilize the full screen size of newer devices instead of getting truncated to previous device dimensions?

Comment: If the screen size is reporting the correct size then your app is not in compatibility mode. It appears that your main window or root controller isn't being sized properly. You need to provide more detail about how it is setup.

Comment: Ok. I think you're right and perhaps I'm not in compatibility mode.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Storyboard check resize view from nib on VC attributes inspector

Size views appropriately for bounds.